# Hölder's inequality for two variables

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, holder-inequality

I have one question about the Hölder's inequality.

Let $f:\Omega \times [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be in $L^{\infty}(\Omega\times[0,\infty))$ and $g: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be in $L^1(\Omega)$. By using the Hölder's inequality, can we conclude that
$\int_{\Omega}f(x,t)g(x)dx \leq ||f||_{L^{\infty}(\Omega\times[0,\infty))}||g||_{L^1(\Omega)}$ ?.

I wasn't sure because domains of $f$ and $g$ are different, $\Omega \times [0,\infty)$ and $\Omega$. How can we directly use Hölder's inequality?

Comment: The inequality holds for almost all $t$. This does not require Holder's inequality. You just have to pull out the bound on the first factor, so no theorem is needed.

Comment: By the definition of essential supremum, we have $|f| \leq ||f||_{L^\infty (\Omega \times [0,\infty))}$ almost everywhere. You mean this fact right?